# how can I ignore an activity in my app?

Tags: java, android

**I designed a login interface from a **firebase** and I want the user to log in only once and then ignore the login interface.**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

```
SignInButton signInButton;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int RC_SING_IN = 9001;
private static final String TAG = "SingInActivity";
private TextView textView;
private ImageView imgAvatar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.busingin);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.busingin:
            singIn();
            break;

    }
}

private void singIn() {
    Intent singInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(singInIntent, RC_SING_IN);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SING_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult : " + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);

        }
    }



@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnecationFailed :" + connectionResult);
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d("TECSTORE", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    Log.d("TECSTORE", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w("TECSTORE", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}
I designed a login interface from a **firebase** and I want the user to log in only once and then ignore the login interface.

Comment: It is not exact duplication of the old question above. The question is specifically related to  Firebase login. While the solution in that old "duplicating" question  is based on  sharedpreference - that is not secure enough to handle details of login. Of course, it's up to developer decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sharedpreference` for this.
First when user enter credentials first time, you put into `sharedpreference`.

```
//Create login session
private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";
        public void createUserLoginSession(String name, String email){
            // Storing login value as TRUE
            editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

            // Storing name in pref
            editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

            // Storing email in pref
            editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

            // commit changes
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Next time check if the user exists or not

```
// Check for login
        public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
            return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
        }

 public boolean checkLogin(){
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

                // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

                // Closing all the Activities from stack
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Please if you can  anser me Arabic

Comment: Please if you know the Arabic language, answer me because I am bad in English

Comment: i don't know arabic. just understand code, you'll know the whole concept

Comment: Sign in with Gmail account not email